# On fractional dimensions with $\dim(A\times B)=\dim A+\dim B$

Tags: reference-request, dimension-theory

The Hausdorff dimension satisfies
$$ \dim A + \dim B \leq \dim (A\times B) $$
while the (upper) packing dimension has
$$ \dim_p (A\times B) \leq \dim_p A + \dim_p B $$
These inequalities hold for any subsets of the Euclidean space.

> 1. Do we know any fractional dimensions with the equation instead of the inequalities?
> 2. Any arguments where it would help to have such a dimension?

For 1. all I can find are statements of the kind: if $A$ and/or $B$ are good enough then one or both of the inequalities above become equations, but nothing for general subsets.

For 2. I found a paper by Darji and Keleti "Covering $\mathbb{R}$ with translates of a compact set" Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 131 (2003), no. 8, 2598–2596.

It seems I might be getting such a dimension, but I can't find any context for it.